How to map through values in nested object
Below is my nested object.
editedFields {
  "TAX_INFORMATION": {
     "TAX VALUE INFORMATION": {
        "Improvement Value": "$812,57"
    }
  }
}
const handleValues = (section: string, key: string, value: string | undefined) {
    console.log(section) - TAX_INFORMATION
    console.log(key) - Improvement Value
    console.log(editedFields[section]?.[key]) - undefined
}

I need the output should be the value "$812,57".
Need some valuable help.

You are missing second tier key TAX VALUE INFORMATION

You can modify the handlevalue as such
const handleValues = (section: string, key: string, value: string | undefined) => {
  console.log(section);
  console.log(key);
  const nestedSection = editedFields[section]["TAX VALUE INFORMATION"];
  console.log(nestedSection[key]);
}

and then call it like this to get $812,57
handleValues("TAX_INFORMATION", "Improvement Value", undefined);

